# Spring SSO with facebook filter and JWT

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0

here is my problem.
I got a first authentication with mail and JWT with Spring boot 1.5.3.
=> works perfectly
Then i made a SSO filter to allow facebook tokens
The thing is, on first authentication it's ok. My server get the Token, then check with fb that says ok then it says ok to my client.
After that if i don't encode my token with my JWT token enhancer, my server says that it is not able to decode it as JSON. 
Just that i know, i would normally not have to encode myself as it should be done automatically after my chain filter if i say ok ??

This code works but i've done the jwt myself, is that possible i've missed something ????

```
public class MyOAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter  extends    OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    public MyOAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(String defaultFilterProcessesUrl) {
        super(defaultFilterProcessesUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        log.info("[attemptAuthentication facebook]");
        Authentication result = null;
        try {
            String token = request.getHeader("oauth_token");
            oauth2ClientContext.setAccessToken(new DefaultOAuth2AccessToken(token));
            result = super.attemptAuthentication(request, response);
            if(result.isAuthenticated()) {
                FacebookService facebookService = new BasicFacebookService(token);
                User fbUser = facebookService.getUser();
                if(fbUser == null) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(" fb user cannot be null");
                }
                if(!userService.isLoginExists(fbUser.getId())) {
                    CreateSocialUserModel model = new CreateSocialUserModel(
                            token,
                            DateUtil.getNow(),
                            "facebook");
                    userService.createSocialUser(model, fbUser);
                }
                //--- Create custom JWT token from facebook token
                UserInfoTokenServices tokenService = new UserInfoTokenServices(
                        "https://graph.facebook.com/me",
                        facebookProperties.getAppId());
                OAuth2AccessToken enhancedToken = jwtTokenEnhancer.enhance(oauth2ClientContext.getAccessToken(),
                        tokenService.loadAuthentication(oauth2ClientContext.getAccessToken().getValue()));
                TokenResponse tokenResponse = new TokenResponse(enhancedToken.getValue(),
                        enhancedToken.getTokenType(),
                        enhancedToken.getRefreshToken() != null ? enhancedToken.getRefreshToken().getValue() : "");

                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                String jsonTokenEnhancedJack = mapper.writeValueAsString(tokenResponse);
                response.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                response.getWriter().flush();
                response.getWriter().print(jsonTokenEnhancedJack);
            }
            return result;
        }  catch (Exception e) {
            log.info("error");
            log.error("error", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  finally {
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I am struggling to implement the same solution, would you mind share more code on your implementation and discussing your thought process, I would like more info on how to use OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter

Comment: Of course, here it is. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As asked by Son Goku just putting some code to help him

First you have to put the filter like this

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher("/**")
            .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and().csrf().disable();
}

private Filter ssoFilter() {
    OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter facebookFilter = new MyOAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter("/user/social");
    OAuth2RestTemplate facebookTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(Oauth2facebook(), oauth2ClientContext);
    facebookFilter.setRestTemplate(facebookTemplate);
    facebookFilter.setTokenServices(new UserInfoTokenServices(
            "https://graph.facebook.com/me",
            facebookProperties.getAppId()
    ));
    return facebookFilter;
}
```

After that you can use the OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter as in first question. 
Also, in first question i customized this method a lot, it works but i was surprised to not find this as easy as these library use to be.
Hope it helps you, i have struggled a bit too on this. 
Maybe now, spring boot handle this much more easily.

Comment: The code you posted above is in your Resource Class for Spring Security OAuth2, the class that extends the ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter? Does this Filter only work on "/user/social". I would not want to place this logic on every Microservice in my architecture, but I do have an Auth Proxy Microservice that allows the user to only send the username/password to the authserver, the auth proxy fills in all the other data. This maybe be a good candidate to have the code above in.

Comment: this code allow this filter to only work with /user/social yes. That also what i wanted.

Comment: Plus i've put it in my class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter but you can put this elsewhere.